# Find of N numbers K numbers xor equalling 0

Tags: c++, performance, permutation, xor, brute-force

My Problem is to find k Numbers in e.g. an Vector/Array with n Numbers, which equal calculated with xor 0. I tried already to brutforce all combinations without repetition, but with n=100 and k=10 the Time Complexity is to high. (about 1.7*10^13 possibilities)

Does anyone have any ideas, to speed up the process of finding the k Numbers in an Array with n Numbers?

I think my approach is not the smartest with such a high number of possibilities, but I really do not know how to make my program faster.

I would appreciate suggestions for a solution.

My program is in C++.

```
SOLUTION comb(int N, int K, const std::vector<KEY>& bit_codes)
{
    std::vector<KEY> chosen_keys;
    std::vector<KEY> failed{KEY(100000, "Error")};
    std::string bitmask(K, 1);
    bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's

    std::vector<int> comb;
    // print integers and permute bitmask
    do {
        comb.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // [0..N-1] integers
        {
            if (bitmask[i]){
                comb.emplace_back(i);
            }
        }
        //do all code till next permutation

        //reserve the size
        for (auto & i : comb) {
            chosen_keys.emplace_back(bit_codes[i]);
        }

        std::string string = chosen_keys[0].bits;
        std::string helper;
        for (size_t i = 1; i < chosen_keys.size(); ++i) {
            helper = to_string(to_bitset(string) ^ to_bitset(chosen_keys[i].bits));
            string = helper;
        }
        for(auto & item: bit_codes){
            if (item.bits == string){
                return {chosen_keys, item};
            }
        }

        chosen_keys.clear();

    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));

    return {failed, KEY(100000, "Error")};
}
```

bitCodes = These are the numbers in a Vector in which I search for the k Numbers, where the xor of them equals 0 (KEY is a class in which bits are saved)

I use these binary Numbers:
All bitCodes:

```
1.  001001101100101001000100101  
2.  101111001100011110101010000  
3.  001111010101110001101001100  
4.  111111100010110100010000001  
5.  000100000011001010001110000  
6.  110101111110101111011011111  
7.  110111011001000010010100110  
8.  111000111001000110101001011  
9.  111001100011011111000110010  
10. 101011001111110110101000111  
11. 100000110010100011010111011  
12. 101110000110011100001010101  
13. 011011110010010111010001101  
14. 100011101111000110100100001  
15. 100001101110001110010111011  
16. 011001011101011000010011110  
17. 101100000110110001011110100  
18. 000111111010001100010001111  
19. 001111101111011100010000010  
20. 001001000111111111011011001
```

There are k=20 and I search n=5 numbers.
The output is:

```
3.  001111010101110001101001100  
4.  111111100010110100010000001  
6.  110101111110101111011011111  
10. 101011001111110110101000111 
12. 101110000110011100001010101
```

...because they equal 0.

The code finished executing after about 100ms for 15504 Possibilities.

Now you can calculate yourself how long it will need to do n=100 and k=10.

Comment: Your program is ***not*** written in "C/C++". There are no such single language as "C/C++", only the two distinct, separate and *very* different languages C and C++. Your code is C++, it can't be built by a C compiler.

Comment: And if you're such a beginner that you can't really tell what language you're programming in, then you should not use so-called "competition" sites to learn programming. Such sites are *not* learning or teaching resources, and using them as such could actually be harmful to your learning process. Read [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and take classes. And stay away from such sites until you know at least a couple of different languages and the basics of computer science.

Comment: `(x xor y) == 0` only when `x == y`

Comment: @pmg A bitCode can be used only once in a possible combination of n numbers, which equals zero.

Comment: Why are you using std::string to store a bit vector and not just uint64_t? How many calls to to_string and to_bitset do you have?

Comment: Ideas: subset sum, xor of k numbers means set bits is even, perhaps Gaussian elimination.

Comment: If you already have the XOR SUM of the last permutation, then you only need to XOR that previous sum with all of the elements that were removed from the last permutation and (also XOR with) all of the elements that were added to the last permutation.  This set of items (to be XOR'd from the sum) is actually the items specified by the previous bitset XOR'd with the current bitset.  (Your `helper` loop is a time waster.  And why so many string-to-bitset-to-string operations? yuck!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For k = 10, n = 100, a brute force approach isn't feasible, since there are over 17 trillion combinations:

```
comb(100,10) = 17310309456440
```

Since the xor of two equal values is zero, my first thought was to reduce the problem to k = 5, n = 100, a bit over 75 million combinations:

```
comb(100,5) = 75287520
```

storing each combination's xor sum, an index count (5), and 5 index values into an array of 75287520 structures. For odd k, such as k = 9, store the 3921225 combinations for k = 4, n = 100 into the array (index count = 4), followed by the 75287520 combinations for k = 5, n = 100 (index count = 5) into the array. To save space, store the number of indexes and the index values as 8 bit unsigned integers.

After creating the array of structures, sort it according to the xor sums. Scan the sorted array looking for equal xor sums (since xor of two equal values is zero), and no duplicates between the two sets of index values, which will be detected when merging the two sets of index values to create a single vector of k index values. If the goal is to find any single set that works, stop here. If the goal is to find all unique sets, use std::map using vector of k index values as the key and an 8 bit integer as the value (the value isn't used, but required by std::map). Note - std::map could consume a lot of space and time if there are a lot of unique sets that xor to zero.

Using a pseudo random number generator to create the array of 100 integers, for k = 10, n = 100, my test code found 4099 unique sets that xor to zero. On my laptop (Intel Core i7-10510U, Win 10 Pro 64 bit, Visual Studio 2019), with radix sort, it takes about 1.5 seconds total time: generate ~= 0.37 seconds, sort ~=0.88 seconds, scan ~= 0.25 seconds, using 1.7 GB of memory.  With quick sort, it take about 6.5 seconds, sort ~= 5.88 seconds, using 0.9 GB of memory

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short     unit16_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

// N numbers xored K at a time

#define K 10
#define N 100

#define K0 (K/2)
#define K1 (K - K0)

typedef struct _SUMIDX {
    uint32_t sum;
    uint8_t cnt;
    uint8_t idx[K1];
}SUMIDX;

clock_t ctTimeBeg;                      // clock values
clock_t ctTimeMid;
clock_t ctTimeEnd;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      Comb(n,k)                                                       //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
static int Comb(int n, int k)
{
uint64_t dvnd = 1;
uint64_t dvsr = 1;
uint64_t quot;
    for(int i = n-k+1; i <= n; i++)
        dvnd *= i;
    for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        dvsr *= i;
    quot = dvnd/dvsr;
    return (int) quot;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      InitCombination - init combination                              //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void InitCombination(std::vector<uint8_t> &x, uint8_t n, uint8_t k) {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < k; i++)
        x[i] = i;
    --x[k-1];
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      NextCombination - generate next combination                     //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
int NextCombination(std::vector<uint8_t> &x, uint8_t n, uint8_t k) {
uint8_t j = k - 1;
    while (j != (uint8_t)(-1) && x[j] == n - k + j)
        --j;
    if (j == (uint8_t)(-1))
        return 0;
    ++x[j];
    for (uint8_t i = j + 1; i < k; ++i)
        x[i] = x[j] + i - j;
    return 1;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      RadixSort                                                       //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
// sort a bin by 3 least significant bytes
void RadixSort3(std::vector<SUMIDX> &sumidx, std::vector<SUMIDX> &rdxsrt, 
                uint32_t beg, uint32_t end)
{
uint32_t mIndex[3][256] = {0};          // count / index matrix
uint32_t i,j,m,n;
SUMIDX u;
    std::swap(sumidx, rdxsrt);          // swap vectors
    for(i = beg; i < end; i++){         // generate histograms
        u.sum = sumidx[i].sum;
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u.sum & 0xff)]++;
            u.sum >>= 8;
        }
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){             // convert to indices
        m = beg;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            n = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = m;
            m += n;
        }
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){             // radix sort
        for(i = beg; i < end; i++){     //  sort by current lsb
            u = sumidx[i];
            m = (u.sum>>(j<<3))&0xff;
            rdxsrt[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        std::swap(sumidx, rdxsrt);      //  swap vectors
    }
}

// split vector into 256 bins according to most significant byte
void RadixSort(std::vector<SUMIDX> &sumidx, std::vector<SUMIDX> &rdxsrt)
{
uint32_t aIndex[260] = {0};             // count / array
uint32_t cnt = (uint32_t)sumidx.size();
uint32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)            // generate histogram
        aIndex[1+(sumidx[i].sum >> 24)]++;
    for(i = 2; i < 257; i++)            // convert to indices
        aIndex[i] += aIndex[i-1];
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)            // sort by msb
        rdxsrt[aIndex[sumidx[i].sum>>24]++] = sumidx[i];
    for(i = 256; i; i--)                // restore aIndex
        aIndex[i] = aIndex[i-1];
    aIndex[0] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)            // radix sort the 256 bins
        RadixSort3(sumidx, rdxsrt, aIndex[i], aIndex[i+1]);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      QuickSort                                                       //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
#define ISZ (24)                // use insertion sort for <= ISZ elements

void InsertionSort(std::vector<SUMIDX> &sumidx, int lo, int hi)
{
    if(lo >= hi)
        return;
    SUMIDX t;
    int i, j;
    lo--;
    for (j = lo + 2; j <= hi; j++) {
        t = sumidx[j];
        i = j-1;
        while(i != lo && sumidx[i].sum > t.sum){
            sumidx[i+1] = sumidx[i];
            i--;
        }
        sumidx[i+1] = t;
    }
}

void QuickSort(std::vector<SUMIDX> &sumidx, int lo, int hi)
{
    while (hi - lo >= ISZ){
        uint32_t p = sumidx[lo + (hi - lo) / 2].sum;
        int i = lo - 1;
        int j = hi + 1;
        while (1){
            while (sumidx[++i].sum < p);
            while (sumidx[--j].sum > p);
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            std::swap(sumidx[i], sumidx[j]);
        }
        if(j - lo < hi - j){
            QuickSort(sumidx, lo, j);
            lo = j+1;
        } else {
            QuickSort(sumidx, j+1, hi);
            hi = j;
        }
    }
    InsertionSort(sumidx, lo, hi);
}

void QuickSort(std::vector<SUMIDX> &sumidx)
{
    QuickSort(sumidx, 0, (int)sumidx.size());
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      Rnd32 - return 32 bit random number                             //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
int Rnd32()
{
static unsigned int r = 0;
    r = r*1664525 + 1013904223;
    return r;
}

#define RDXSRT 1

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int c, c0, c1;                          // combinations
    int sxi = 0;                            // index to sumidx
    c0 = Comb(N, K0);                       // generate # of combinations
    c1 = Comb(N, K1);
    c = c0;
    if (K0 != K1)
        c = c0 + c1;
    std::vector<SUMIDX> sumidx(c);          // vector of sums and indexes
#if RDXSRT
    std::vector<SUMIDX> rdxsrt(c);          // vector for radix sort
#endif
    std::vector<int> v(N);                  // vector of numbers
    std::vector<uint8_t> x(K);              // vector of indexes
    std::map<std::vector<uint8_t>, uint8_t> m;            // map of sets of K indexes
    std::map<std::vector<uint8_t>, uint8_t>::iterator mi; // iterator for m
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        v[i] = Rnd32();
    ctTimeBeg = clock();
    // generate vector of sums and indexes
    InitCombination(x, N, K0);
    while (NextCombination(x, N, K0)) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < K0; i++)
            sum ^= v[x[i]];
        sumidx[sxi].sum = sum;
        sumidx[sxi].cnt = K0;
        for (int i = 0; i < K0; i++)
            sumidx[sxi].idx[i] = x[i];
        sxi++;
        }
#if (K0 != K1)
    InitCombination(x, N, K1);
    while (NextCombination(x, N, K1)) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < K1; i++)
            sum ^= v[x[i]];
        sumidx[sxi].sum = sum;
        sumidx[sxi].cnt = K1;
        for (int i = 0; i < K1; i++)
            sumidx[sxi].idx[i] = x[i];
        sxi++;
    }
#endif
    ctTimeMid = clock();
    std::cout << "# of ticks " << ctTimeMid - ctTimeBeg << std::endl;
    // sort the vector according to the sums
#if RDXSRT
    RadixSort(sumidx, rdxsrt);
#else
    QuickSort(sumidx);
#endif
#if 0
    std::sort(sumidx.begin(), sumidx.end(),
        [](SUMIDX s0, SUMIDX s1)
        {return s0.sum < s1.sum;});
#endif
    ctTimeEnd = clock();
    std::cout << "# of ticks " << ctTimeEnd - ctTimeMid << std::endl;
    ctTimeMid = ctTimeEnd;
    // scan the sorted vector for equal sums
    for (int i = 0; i < c - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < c; j++) {
            if (sumidx[i].sum != sumidx[j].sum)
                break;
#if (K0 != K1)
            if (K != (sumidx[i].cnt + sumidx[j].cnt))
                continue;
#endif
            //  merge indexes
            int ii = 0, jj = 0, im = 0;
            while (1) {
                // if duplicate indexes skip
                if (sumidx[i].idx[ii] == sumidx[j].idx[jj])
                    break;
                if (sumidx[i].idx[ii] < sumidx[j].idx[jj]) {
                    x[im++] = sumidx[i].idx[ii++];
                    if (ii >= sumidx[i].cnt) {
                        do
                            x[im++] = sumidx[j].idx[jj++];
                        while (jj < sumidx[j].cnt);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    x[im++] = sumidx[j].idx[jj++];
                    if (jj >= sumidx[j].cnt) {
                        do
                            x[im++] = sumidx[i].idx[ii++];
                        while (ii < sumidx[i].cnt);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (im != K)                // if duplicate indexes skip
                continue;
            m[x];                       // insert if unique set
        }
    }
    ctTimeEnd = clock();
    std::cout << "# of ticks " << ctTimeEnd - ctTimeMid << std::endl;
    std::cout << "# of ticks " << ctTimeEnd - ctTimeBeg << std::endl;
    std::cout << "number of combinations found " << m.size() << std::endl;
#if 1                                   // show and check what was found
    for (mi = m.begin(); mi != m.end(); mi++) {
        x = mi->first;
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << (uint32_t) x[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
           sum ^= v[x[i]];
        if (sum != 0)
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
#endif
    return(0);
}
```

---

The above code would work for 128 bit keys, N=111, K=11 on a system with 64GB. To reduce the amount of memory used, the code below only stores entries for N=111, K=5, and calculates xor and does a binary search for the combinations of N=111, K=6. It can run on a system with 16GB of memory. It's much slower than the above code, taking a bit less than 4 minutes on my laptop. The binary search was modified to search for the first matching entry. I did some simple tests to confirm it's working, but haven't done exhaustive test to make sure there aren't any issues.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short     unit16_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

// N numbers xored K at a time

#define K 11
#define N 111

#define K0 (K/2)
#define K1 (K - K0)

typedef struct _SUMIDX {
    uint64_t sum[2];
    uint8_t idx[K0];
}SUMIDX;

clock_t ctTimeBeg;                      // clock values
clock_t ctTimeMid;
clock_t ctTimeEnd;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      Comb(n,k)                                                       //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
static uint32_t Comb(uint32_t n, uint32_t k)
{
uint64_t dvnd = 1;
uint64_t dvsr = 1;
uint64_t quot;
    for(uint32_t i = n-k+1; i <= n; i++)
        dvnd *= i;
    for(uint32_t i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        dvsr *= i;
    quot = dvnd/dvsr;
    return (uint32_t) quot;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      InitCombination - init combination                              //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void InitCombination(uint8_t x[], uint8_t n, uint8_t k) {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < k; i++)
        x[i] = i;
    --x[k-1];
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      NextCombination - generate next combination                     //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
uint32_t NextCombination(uint8_t x[], uint8_t n, uint8_t k) {
uint8_t j = k - 1;
    while (j != (uint8_t)(-1) && x[j] == n - k + j)
        --j;
    if (j == (uint8_t)(-1))
        return 0;
    ++x[j];
    for (uint8_t i = j + 1; i < k; ++i)
        x[i] = x[j] + i - j;
    return 1;
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      RadixSort                                                       //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
// sort a bin by 15 least significant bytes
void RadixSort7(SUMIDX sumidx[], SUMIDX rdxsrt[],
                uint32_t beg, uint32_t end)
{
uint32_t mIndex[15][256] = {0};         // count / index matrix
uint32_t i,j,m,n;
SUMIDX u;
    std::swap(sumidx, rdxsrt);          // swap array pointers
    for(i = beg; i < end; i++){         // generate histograms
        u.sum[0] = sumidx[i].sum[0];
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u.sum[0] & 0xff)]++;
            u.sum[0] >>= 8;
        }
        u.sum[1] = sumidx[i].sum[1];
        for(j = 8; j < 15; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u.sum[1] & 0xff)]++;
            u.sum[1] >>= 8;
        }
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 15; j++){            // convert to indices
        m = beg;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            n = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = m;
            m += n;
        }
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){             // radix sort
        for(i = beg; i < end; i++){     //  sort by current lsb
            u = sumidx[i];
            m = (u.sum[0]>>(j<<3))&0xff;
            rdxsrt[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        std::swap(sumidx, rdxsrt);      //  swap array pointers
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {           // radix sort
        for(i = beg; i < end; i++){     //  sort by current lsb
            u = sumidx[i];
            m = (u.sum[1]>>(j<<3))&0xff;
            rdxsrt[mIndex[8+j][m]++] = u;
        }
        std::swap(sumidx, rdxsrt);      //  swap array pointers
    }
}

// split vector into 256 bins according to most significant byte
void RadixSort(SUMIDX sumidx[], SUMIDX rdxsrt[], uint32_t cnt)
{
uint32_t aIndex[260] = {0};             // count / array
uint32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)            // generate histogram
        aIndex[1+(sumidx[i].sum[1] >> 56)]++;
    for(i = 2; i < 257; i++)            // convert to indices
        aIndex[i] += aIndex[i-1];
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)            // sort by msb
        rdxsrt[aIndex[sumidx[i].sum[1] >>56]++] = sumidx[i];
    for(i = 256; i; i--)                // restore aIndex
        aIndex[i] = aIndex[i-1];
    aIndex[0] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)            // radix sort the 256 bins
        RadixSort7(sumidx, rdxsrt, aIndex[i], aIndex[i+1]);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      BinSrc  return index to first match                             //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
uint32_t BinSrc(SUMIDX sumidx[], uint64_t x[2], uint32_t cnt)
{
uint32_t lo = 0;
uint32_t hi = cnt;
uint32_t i;
    while((hi - lo) > 1){               // find a match
        i = (lo + hi)/2;
        if((x[1] <  sumidx[i].sum[1]) ||
           (x[1] == sumidx[i].sum[1]) &&
           (x[0] <  sumidx[i].sum[0])){
            hi = i;
            continue;
        }
        if((x[1] >  sumidx[i].sum[1]) ||
           (x[1] == sumidx[i].sum[1]) &&
           (x[0] >  sumidx[i].sum[0])){
            lo = i;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    hi = i;                             // find first match
    while (hi != lo) {
        i = (lo + hi) / 2;
        if ((x[1] == sumidx[i].sum[1]) &&
            (x[0] == sumidx[i].sum[0])) {
            hi = i;
            continue;
        }
        if ((x[1] >  sumidx[i].sum[1]) ||
            (x[1] == sumidx[i].sum[1]) &&
            (x[0] >  sumidx[i].sum[0])) {
            lo = i+1;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if((x[1] == sumidx[lo].sum[1]) &&
       (x[0] == sumidx[lo].sum[0]))
        return lo;
    return uint32_t(0-1);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      Rnd64 - return 64 bit random number                             //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
uint64_t Rnd64()                        // random 64 bit integer
{
static uint64_t r = 1ull;
    r = r * 6364136223846793005ull + 1442695040888963407ull;
    return r;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//      Rnd32 - return 32 bit random number                             //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
uint32_t Rnd32()
{
static uint32_t r = 0;
    r = r*1664525 + 1013904223;
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    uint64_t sum[2];                        // 128 bit key
    uint32_t c0;                            // combinations(N, K0)
    uint32_t xi;                            // index to sumidx
    uint32_t i, ii, jj, im;
    c0 = Comb(N, K0);                       // generate # of combinations
    SUMIDX *sumidx = new SUMIDX[c0];        // array of xors + indexes
    SUMIDX *rdxsrt = new SUMIDX[c0];        // array for radix sort
    uint64_t v[N][2];
    uint8_t x[K1];
    uint8_t m[K];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
      v[i][0] = Rnd64()&0x000000000000ffffull;
      v[i][1] = Rnd64()&0xffffffff00000000ull;
    }
    ctTimeBeg = clock();
    // generate array of xors and indexes
    xi = 0;
    InitCombination(x, N, K0);
    while (NextCombination(x, N, K0)) {
        sum[1] = sum[0] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < K0; i++){
            sum[0] ^= v[x[i]][0];
            sum[1] ^= v[x[i]][1];
        }
        sumidx[xi].sum[0] = sum[0];
        sumidx[xi].sum[1] = sum[1];
        for (i = 0; i < K0; i++)
            sumidx[xi].idx[i] = x[i];
        xi++;
        }
    ctTimeMid = clock();
    std::cout << "# of ticks " << ctTimeMid - ctTimeBeg << std::endl;
    // sort the vector according to the sums
    RadixSort(sumidx, rdxsrt, c0);
    ctTimeEnd = clock();
    std::cout << "# of ticks " << ctTimeEnd - ctTimeMid << std::endl;
    ctTimeMid = ctTimeEnd;
    // scan the sorted vector for equal xors
    InitCombination(x, N, K1);
#if 0
    uint32_t z = K1;
#endif
    while (NextCombination(x, N, K1)) {
#if 0
        if (z != x[1]) {
            z = x[1];
            for (i = 0; i < K1; i++)
                std::cout << std::setw(3) << (uint32_t)x[i] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
#endif
        sum[1] = sum[0] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < K1; i++){
            sum[0] ^= v[x[i]][0];
            sum[1] ^= v[x[i]][1];
        }
        i = BinSrc(sumidx, sum, c0);
        if(i == uint32_t(0-1))
            continue;
        while((sum[0] == sumidx[i].sum[0]) &&
              (sum[1] == sumidx[i].sum[1])){
            //  merge indexes
            ii = jj = im = 0;
            while (1) {
                // if duplicate indexes skip
                if (sumidx[i].idx[ii] == x[jj])
                    break;
                if (sumidx[i].idx[ii] <  x[jj]) {
                    m[im++] = sumidx[i].idx[ii++];
                    if (ii >= K0) {
                        do
                            m[im++] =x[jj++];
                        while (jj < K1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    m[im++] = x[jj++];
                    if (jj >= K1) {
                        do
                            m[im++] = sumidx[i].idx[ii++];
                        while (ii < K0);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (im == K)                // if not duplicate indexes stop
                goto found0;
            i++;
        }
    }
found0:
    ctTimeEnd = clock();
    std::cout << "# of ticks " << ctTimeEnd - ctTimeMid << std::endl;
    std::cout << "# of ticks " << ctTimeEnd - ctTimeBeg << std::endl;
    if(im != K){
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
        goto exit0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < K; i++)
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << (uint32_t)m[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    sum[1] = sum[0] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < K; i++){
        sum[0] ^= v[m[i]][0];
        sum[1] ^= v[m[i]][1];
    }
    if (sum[0] != 0 || sum[1] != 0)
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
exit0:
    delete rdxsrt;
    delete sumidx;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What can we do to make the program more effective with higher N and K?

Comment: There are ten key cards with 128-bit code that open 10 locks. There is also one card additionally which contains the exclusive or of all ten key cards. Unfortunately, these 11 cards are lost in the stack of 111 other cards (also with 128-bit code). Now I shall find those 11 cards (10 key cards and 1 exclusive or card) in those 111 cards.

Comment: My computer has 32GB, and there is no information about memory limit, but I guess it shall work on a standard computer.

Comment: @R2D2 - once you've found the 11 key cards, there is no way to determine which card is the xor card. Each card will be the xor of the other 10 cards. Any progress on this? I created some test code to confirm that the strategy will work. It can run on a system with 16GB of memory.

Comment: How can I work with 128 bit long numbers?

Comment: I tried your Code with 32bit Codes N=111, K=11, but the program never showed any result. It takes to long. Do you have any improvements for the code? Do you had some results for N=111 and K=11?

Comment: @R2D2 - I updated my answer with test code. I haven't fully tested the binary search for first match, but it seems to be working. If this is a classroom assignment, it may appear you had too much help.